# Mkdir in Shell Script not creating folder in mac OS while executing using java

Tags: java, shell

**cmdFile.sh:**

```
cd "E:\\myWorkSpace\\sampleTest"
mkdir "E:\\myWorkSpace\\sampleTest\output"
```

**Java:**

```
runtime.exec("cmdFile.sh");
```

The above shell script creates the folder if executed through a command prompt. But, if it is executed using Java, then the folder is not created.

Comment: [Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) you have an example how to run external programm with reading error and outputstream, so you can see if you get an error while running ` cmdFile.sh`

Comment: @sri: What error do you get from Java?

Comment: These are windows file paths, not Mac OS

Answer (score 2):

[`runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) actually executes a process. Did you mark `cmdFile.sh` as an executable? Otherwise you should run the following in your terminal first:

```
chmod +x cmdFile.sh
```

Otherwise you should call a shell with `cmdFile.sh` as argument, for instance:

```
runtime.exec("/bin/bash cmdFile.sh");
```

---

On a sidenote, you can write te script in Java as well (so you don't need to start an additional process):

```
File f = new File("E:\\myWorkSpace\\sampleTest\\output");
boolean wasSuccessfull = f.mkdir(); //or mkdirs if there are more possible nonexisting parent-folders.
```